# F#: writing a function for maxCubeVolume?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm working on a homework assignment and need to write a function in F# that takes a list of floating point tuples that represent dimensions of a cube (length, width, and height) and returns the volume of the cube that has the largest volume.

Each tuple consists of three floating point values that are all greater than zero. The volume of the cube is computed using (length x width x height). If the list is empty, return 0.0.

I really don't know how to implement this in F# when we aren't allowed to use immutable variables, `List.map` or `max` either.

What I've done so far is:

```
let listTup = [(2.1, 3.4, 1.8); (4.7, 2.8, 3.2); (0.9, 6.1, 1.0);]
let cubeVolume (x, y, z) : float = x * y * z
let maxCubeVolume tupleList = ???
```

`maxCubeVolume listTup` should return 42.112

How do I do this in F#?

Comment: Start with a recursive function that carries the max volume and tuple for it. Call it with an initial value of (0,0,0) 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
//using the "not allowed" List.map and List.max
[(2.1, 3.4, 1.8); (4.7, 2.8, 3.2); (0.9, 6.1, 1.0)]
|> List.map (fun (l,w,h) -> l*w*h) |> List.max

//using List.fold: the if branch could be a max vol acc, but you said max wasn't allowed
(0.,[(2.1, 3.4, 1.8); (4.7, 2.8, 3.2); (0.9, 6.1, 1.0)])
||> List.fold (fun acc (l,w,h) -> l*w*h |> fun vol -> if vol > acc then vol else acc)

//using List.maxBy
let vol (l,w,h) = l*w*h
[(2.1, 3.4, 1.8); (4.7, 2.8, 3.2); (0.9, 6.1, 1.0)]
|> List.maxBy vol |> vol

//using List.sortBy
let vol (l,w,h) = l*w*h
[(2.1, 3.4, 1.8); (4.7, 2.8, 3.2); (0.9, 6.1, 1.0)]
|> List.sortBy (vol >> (*)-1.) |> List.head |> vol
```